# Export/save dicom RT Structure Set

Tags: python, c++, save, dicom, pydicom

I am looking a for way to export/save rt structure sets to dicom file. I have an algorithm for segmentation structures which outputs a set of contours which I would like to export to dicom rtstructset.

My language of preference is Python, however a C/C++ solution would work if I can add a Python wrapper to it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have practically no experience of DICOM in Python myself, but would this library be sufficient for your needs: http://code.google.com/p/pydicom/ ?

Comment: As far as I know that library does not support exporting rt structure sets.

Comment: actually it turns out it is possible to export dicom rt structure sets in pydicom... I was just not using the lib properly